# Treepanel expand/collapse on a node without children Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, tree

I am using ExtJs 4.2. Am using property `useArrows:true` in my tree panel. How to show the collapse/expand icon on a node without children in a tree panel.On expand and collapse it should fire all the events related to the tree panel.

I tried adding

1-`children:[{}]` gave me undefined property.

2-`loaded:true` nothing happened

3-`singleExpand:true` nothing happened

4-`allowChildren:true` nothing happened

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One hack is to actually add children items to the node but hide them with css.
So you would do something like:

```
#tree_element_id .x-grid-tree-node-leaf{
  display:none;
}
```